# Getting result back of webview operation

Tags: android, paypal, android-webview

I am implementing payment functionality in my application. For that, I am launching my website's payment page with new intent (startActivityForResult) on a click of a button from my application. Once the payment is succeed, I want that webview to be closed automatically and should get succeed of failed result back in calling activity. Is it possible and if yes, how can I achieve this?

Comment: could you specify what version of android and type of design you are making use of?

Comment: I am supporting from Android 2.2 to Android 4.4.
If this design of launching webview dose not work, may I do it using paypal integration in Android? If yes, How will I get the success result that payment is dine successfully?

Comment: I can suggest couple of approaches:
1. WebView using JSON object
2. Paid Libraries that help your gateway payment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not completely aware of your use case. If are are just trying to accept credit cards or accept paypal as a form of payment, check out https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK and check out the https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/tree/master/SampleApp. The sdk takes care of redirection to PayPal for you so that you do not need to implement that yourself via an webview.